# Clarifying meaning of 満系

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a Japanese term paper and have come across the term 満系, in this context:

> 日系軍官の満系統制

I am guessing based on the context and searching for possible meanings that it equates to something like 'Manchurian', as in 'Manchurian control', but would love confirmation of this by someone who may recognize this term. Thank you.

**Edit:** I was asked to add another sentence for more context of 満系 in the paper I'm reading, it only comes up one other time so here it is:

> 以上のような「次官政治」への移行が**満系**の強い反発を呼ぶことは事前に予想できたことであった。

Comment: I think you guessed it right. 滿洲 is Manchuria, but we need more context or sentences to know exactly what it means. It reads like "Japanese military officer's control over Manchuria's **something**".

Comment: @Rathony Ok, thanks for the confirmation! The whole sentence is a heading and is "満洲国軍の発展と軍事顧問・日系軍官の満系統制", sorry for just posting part of it (I thought that would be sufficient and didn't want to clutter my question.)

Comment: It is better to write as many sentences as possible. The sentence in your comment is not that helpful. Please edit your question with more sentences.

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly as you guessed.

「[満系]{まんけい}」＝「[満州系]{まんしゅうけい}」＝ "Manchurian", "belonging/pertaining to Manchuria or Manchurians"

This word is used pretty much exclusively in the ***context of Japanese control of Manchuria***.  We say 「[中国系]{ちゅうごくけい}アメリカ[人]{じん}」 to mean "Chinese-Americans".  We never say 「満系アメリカ人」.

> 「[日系軍官]{にっけいぐんかん}の満系[統制]{とうせい}」

therefore, means "***Manchurian control by Japanese military***".

> 「満系の[強]{つよ}い[反発]{はんぱつ}」

means "***Strong repellence by the Manchurians***"